# Tomcat adding Newline to Request Body after certain number of Chars?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have been experiencing an issue where newlines are added to an (XML) Request Body for my Spring Boot application running on a standalone Tomcat server, whenever a single line exceeds some number (49.153) of chars.

Sent Request Body:

```
<body>
fooobaarfooobaarfooobaarfooobaarfooobaarfoooobarfoooobar
</body>
```

Received Request in Application Layer:

```
<body>
fooobaarfooobaar
fooobaarfooobaar
fooobaarfoooobar
foooobar
</body>
```

Anyone had this experience or know what could be causing the issue? Adjusting max post size or swallow sizes has not helped. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange. How did you print the XML?

Comment: Spring Boots logs.

Comment: And you are sure that the line breaks are not from the logger?

Comment: Not 100%! But the request body fails a signature validation when the request size is smaller (no line breaks in logs).

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I actually can't because the environment is on my work computer (I'm posting this on my personal laptop because of worries around confidentiality) and reproducing it would be too challenging. I hoped maybe it was a known/common issue - seems like it might be multiple things. Either way, thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I can now confirm that the issue was in fact that spring boot logging added the newlines. Please add it as the answer - thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only see the output of the logging framework.

The message is not affected.